# ConEmu - Is there a way to change the title to match the server I've SSH ed onto?

Tags: linux, cygwin, conemu

I use conemu with cygwin to ssh on to various servers. I was wondering if there was a way to automatically rename the tab using the alias, so I know where I am.

I have tried creating a new tab from the CLI using `sh --login -i -new_console:t"Test"` but I keep getting

> sh: -w: invalid option.

If I could somehow automate one of these tasks using my `.bashrc` alias or a setting with the application it would make a great tool even greater.

Thanks, D

Answer (score 1):

This solution doesn't automatically rename the tab with the remote host name, but maybe it will fit your need.

Go to `Settings`->`Startup`->`Tasks`, create a new task with `+` and in the big rectangle `Commands` enter:

```
ssh user@remote -new_console:t:"My Tab Title"
```